# How to mathematically solve for a binary vector whose dot product with a matrix gives a non-binary vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is a bit of a long post, so two quick notes.

1.) I am a biologist by trade so I apologize if I misuse terminology or notation. I encourage clarifying edits to both the Title and Body!

2.) Thanks for taking the time to read through and consider my question!

---

My current project involves assigning simulated data to regions of a scatterplot based on the that regions local density.

I have a binary matrix, $A$, that represents whether a simulated point (column) falls in a region (row). Regions can overlap which is why columns can have multiple 1s in them.

$$\begin{equation*}
A_{m,n} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & a_{1,n} \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & a_{2,n} \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
1 & 1 & \cdots & a_{m,n} 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$$

I also have a non-binary vector, $Y$, of length $m$ (the number of regions) that represents the number of simulated points that I expect to see in each region:
$$\begin{equation*}
Y_{m,1} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
7 \\
22  \\
\vdots  \\
y_{m} 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$$

I am trying to determine a **binary** vector, $X$, of length $n$ that when multiplied with $A$, gives Y:

$$\begin{equation*}
X_{n,1} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1  \\
\vdots  \\
x_{n} 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$$

I think this is the correct formulation:
$$
A \cdot \textbf{X} = Y
$$

Here is an example:

$$\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1  & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1\\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$$

In other words, I need (to sum the rows of) columns 1, 3, and 4 (AKA simulated points 1,3,4) to attain my "expected points in each region" vector.

My attempt: I understand that there are some scenarios where there are multiple solutions and other scenarios where there are no solutions. I wrote a metropolis algorithm that would randomly sample, $Y$, until it finds the best $Y$ that minimizes the cost function. But usually it takes a while to run...

**My question:** Given $A$ and $Y$, is there a way to mathematically solve for $\textbf{X}$?

Answer (score 1):

Another way of stating your problem: you want to express the vector $\bf Y$ as the sum of a subset of columns of the matrix $\bf A$.

The problem is NP-complete.  For example, the [Exact cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) is the case of your problem where all elements of $Y$ are $1$.  So we don't expect an efficient (polynomial-time) algorithm to exist.

Comment: Exactly! For a vector of length 30k, there are 2^30k combinations.  Do you know if there are any algorithms (or regression analyses?) that find solutions which are good approximations?

Comment: I might try tabu search or simulated annealing or a genetic algorithm.